# Simulating planet orbit with vectors

Tags: c++, vectormath

To better understand how vectors work, I'm trying to create a very simple simulation of the earth orbiting the sun. Currently, all I want is for the earth to go around the sun in a circle. No laws of physics are taken into account.

I thought that what I was doing would work, however it creates some kind of a movement into a fibonacci spiral.

```
// initial positions
vec2 sun(0.0,0.0);
vec2 earth(10.0,0.0);

while(true) {

    vec2 earthToSun = normalize(sun - earth); // this is the vector 'pointing from the earth towards the sun'
    vec2 speedVector = vec2(-earthToSun.y, earthToSun.x); // this is the vector perpendicular to the earthToSun vector

    earth = earth + earthToSun + speedVector; // move the earth along the resulting vector

}
```

What is wrong in my calculations?

Comment: I knew that tag couldn't possibly be for what you used it for when I saw it.

Comment: try using 0.0, 10.0 and so on instead of integers

Comment: I removed the orbit tag and tested with floats, still the same.

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp, Technically, those are doubles. It shouldn't matter, though.

Comment: Ugh. I meant doubles but I keep mixing up the words (since a double is just a double precision floating point)

Comment: `earth = earth + earthToSun + speedVector;` moves the earth by 1 towards the sun and by 1 in a perpendicular direction. This is not a circle orbit.

Comment: @Inspired I see. I figured that is how the orbiting in our solar system works? The planet has a certain velocity-vector, but the gravity makes it go in an ellipse. Multiplying the speedVector with a certain scalar factor makes the earth turn around the sun for a longer period of time. Makes me wonder if the earth is ever going to 'hit' the sun.

Comment: Well, given a quantum of time `t`, and given `sun` position, `earth` position and `earthVelocity`, you can approximately calculate the new earth's position and velocity via: `acceleration = K*normalize(sun-earth); earth = earth + earthVelocity*t + acceleration*t*t/2.0; earthVelocity = earthVelocity + t*acceleration;` where `K` is some constant. But the  earth will rather quick hit the sun (or flow away) anyway because of discrete nature of the simulation.

Comment: See my edited answer. I suspect your `normalize` does not divide by the squared distance. The acceleration drops squared with distance, not linearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do it with trigonometry:

```
#define PI 3.1415926
float r = 10.0;
for (int theta=0; theta<2*PI; theta += 0.01)
{
    float x = r*cos(theta),
          y = r*sin(theta);
    earth = vec2(x, y);
}
```

Obviously, alter the period, starting value of `theta`, increment, etc. as you see fit.

Comment: I have already created the simulation this way, but my goal is to eventually base it all on the laws of Newton and Kepler, and create a more realistic simulation. And I need vectors for that. I also want to get used to vector math.

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp Well, [those laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion) analyze planetary motion in terms of angle/angular velocity.  Trying to add a vector is probably the wrong approach since it necessarily moves earth on a tangent off the orbit.  You only get a proper orbit when your step -> 0.  A trigonometric approach might actually end up being more easy extend to encompass the actual laws.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial conditions should be

```
vec2 sun(0.0,0.0);
vec2 earth(10.0,0.0);
vec2 speedVector = vec2(-earthToSun.y, earthToSun.x);
```

That looks good. However, there are two problems with your equations.

1. The position of your earth should change over time like this:

   ```
   vec2 earthToSun = normalize(sun - earth);
   earth = earth + earthToSun;  // no speedVector added here
   ```

   Note that I did *not* add `speedVector` to earth in the update code. What you did there is accelerate your earth throughout your simulation.
2. Your `normalize` function will have to normalize by the *squared* distance. I am not sure how you implemented that. *F* = *g*  *m1*  *m2* / *r* ^ 2. I suspect that your `normalize` only devides by *r*, not *r* ^ 2. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant for reference

Your earth will not necessarily go in a circle. Most likely it will be an elliptical orbit. Also make sure to choose a small enough step size. Per iteration, `earth` should change only by a small fraction of its distance to the sun, or otherwise you will accumulate obvious integration errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is the same (except for the slower speed, ofcourse).

Comment: `earth = earth + earthToSun;` will just drop the earth to the sun.